# How to group dates in mongoDB by first or second half of the month (fortnights)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

With the following data structure, using mongoDB's (v3.4) aggregation framework how do you group information every 15 days?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cb10a201e20af7503305fea"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5b21240c4e71161fdd40b27c"),
    "version" : NumberLong(2),
    "value" : 42,
    "itemRef" : ObjectId("5cb10a201e20af7503305fe9"),
    "status" : "ACCEPTED",
    "date" : ISODate("2019-04-13T11:00:00.466Z")
}
```

the required output would be:

```
[date: 2019/01/01, totalValue:15],
[date: 2019/01/16, totalValue:5],
[date: 2019/02/01, totalValue:25],
[date: 2019/02/16, totalValue:30]
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I found to resolve this problem with mongoDB 3.4 was using $cond + $dayOfMonth to define in which part of the month this date is.

```
db.contract.aggregate(
[
  {$match:{...queryGoesHere...}},
  {$project:
    {dateText:
      {$cond:
        [
          {$lte:[{$dayOfMonth:$date},15]},
          ['$dateToString': ['format': '%Y-%m-01', 'date': '$date']], 
          ['$dateToString': ['format': '%Y-%m-16', 'date': '$date']]
        ]
      }
     value:'$value'
    }
  },
  {$group:
    {
      _id:'$dateText',
      total:{'$sum':1}
    }
  }
]
```

The solution is in the projection of the "dateText", it first uses the $cond to determine if the date is in the first or second part of the month. It determines this using the '$dayOfMonth' which returs the day in the month. If it is less or equal to 15, it uses the '$dateToString' to format the date by year-month-01 else it formats it to year-month-16.

Hope this can help someone in the future.